# MySQL How to Order By a Case in Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

I've kind of hit a brick wall here. Not sure if this is feasible but thought i'd give StackOverflow a try. I have a Select statement with a Case within the select statement. For example:

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN A.X = 1 THEN B.A
      WHEN A.X = 2 THEN B.B
      ELSE B.C
   END AS `Example`,
   A.Y,
   A.Z
   .....
```

I'd like to order by `Example`. Anyone know how to properly write this?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `ORDER BY Example`?

Comment: If `order by Example` doesn't work, try `order by 1`. You can use column numbers after `order by` instead of column names.

Comment: Thanks guys! Both answers work!